# How to synchronise access to database in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I have three threads:

```
    thread1:
    run() {
     while(true) {
      List<Document> documents = getDocumentsFromExternalService()
      //executes "insert into .." sql query:
      insertDocumentsToDatabase(documents)
      Thread.sleep(5000);
     }
    }

    thread2:
    run() {
     while(true) {
      //connects to database and execute "Select * from DOCS WHERE DOCS.STATE='STATE_1" query:
      List<Documents> docs = getDocumentsFromDatabaseWithState("STATE_1") 
      docsChanged = doSomethingWith(docs)
      //perform "update" SQL instruction:
      updateDocumentsInDatabase(docsChanged)
      Thread.sleep(5000);
     }
    } 

    thread3:
    run() {
     while(true) {
      //connects to database and execute "Select * from DOCS WHERE DOCS.STATE='STATE_2'" query:
      List<Documents> docs = getDocumentsFromDatabaseWithState("STATE_2") 
      docsChanged = doSomethingOtherWith(docs)
      //perform "update" SQL instruction:
      updateDocumentsInDatabase(docsChanged)
      Thread.sleep(5000);
     }
    }
```

All connections are standard JDBC connection and separate for every thread. The question is how can I achieve thread safety? It means - how to be sure that before executing reading function from thread2 thread 3 isn't writing to database?

Comment: You could use locks, you could use flags....

Comment: You could also use a single `Connection` in which case SQL statements would be executed sequentially (for example a connection pool with 1 connection only).

Comment: `The Oracle JDBC drivers provide full support for, and are highly optimized for, applications that use Java multithreading. Controlled serial access to a connection, such as that provided by connection caching, is both necessary and encouraged. However, Oracle strongly discourages sharing a database connection among multiple threads. Avoid allowing multiple threads to access a connection simultaneously. If multiple threads must share a connection, use a disciplined begin-using/end-using protocol`.

Comment: I was referring to a connection pool with 1 connection only where each thread must use `getConnection()` to acquire it and `Connection.close()` to release it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in reading while another thread is writing. The database is thread-safe, and ACID. Why do you think you have to do any synchronization? The database will handle that for you.

Comment: Why not use transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Use transactions in the database for the writes.

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
// do you're thing
connection.commit();
connection.setAutoCommit(true);
```

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: I use transaction for every "commit" function from all threads (with rollback, if commit fails)